# How to add gesture to custom UICollectionViewCell NIB?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nib

I have a ViewController with a UIImage (Basically a rectangle).  I have a tap and long press gesture wired up to the UIImage.  When I tap on the image, my app responds accordingly.

However, now I have to expand the app.  Instead of a UIImage in the middle of the app, I know have a UICollectionView, with the same image in one of the cells.  The cell is also a custom cell using a NIB.  How do I now access the UIImage in the NIB to act how it once did when it was just in the ViewController all by itself?

Answer (score 0):

If your `UICollectionView` is just a grid of images that react to being tapped then you can do this using the following method:

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and run whatever function you need when the user taps a cell

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I should have clarified.  The reason I am using a Tap gesture, as I need to determine where in the image the user taps.  When the user taps on the image, it returns the coordinates of the tap.  didSelectItemAt wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Therefore create a custom class for your `UICollectionViewCell` and add your `UITapGestureRecogniser` in there

Comment: It doesn't appear that is possible.  I can add the gesture to the entire collection view, but I really need to narrow it to just the uimage in 2 cells.

Comment: `let shotGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(shotOnNet)` `collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(shotGesture)` works but the entire collection view gets the gesture

Comment: That's because you're adding the gesture to the entire collection view and not the cell. As I mentioned earlier create a custom class for your `UICollectionViewCell` and put your gesture in there